# Display bash code in LaTeX

Tags: code

Is it possible to display bash code in LaTeX? Like the next one:

```
Here is the code's format i want to show in latex
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In LaTeX, in order to display bash code and any other code, you can use the [`listings`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) package.

The `\lstset` command is used to control the basic appearance, including the language of code. Please see page 13 of [`listings`](http://ctan.imsc.res.in/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) documentation.

The code to be displayed may be part of the LaTeX file or may be an external file.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=bash,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily
}

\begin{document}

Code directly embedded in \LaTeX\ file.

\begin{lstlisting}
  Here is the code's format i want to show in latex
\end{lstlisting}

Code from an external file.

\lstinputlisting{my.bash}

\end{document}
```

---

Other possible/related options for tasks like the above are (not in any particular order):

- [lstaddons](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lstaddons)
- [minted](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted)
- [examplep](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/examplep)
- [progkeys](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/progkeys)
- [verbatim](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/verbatim)

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't found an easy answer to this. Should it works for reportclass?

Comment: @santimirandarp Yes, why not? Updated my answer for `report` class. Now you can accept my answer and upvote it. :-)

Comment: Yes, i will try it and accept and upvote if it works...thank you again.

Comment: you might add `verbatim` to that list.  it doesn't have as many bells and whistles, but is simple, reliable, and maintained by the latex team so when something sneaky changes under the covers, it doesn't fall apart.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes, of course. How could I miss that?